# Обновление статистики работы почтового сервера в awstats через веб интерфейс

Tags: linux

Доброго всем времени суток!

Установил `awstats` на `centos` 5.6 для отображения статистики работы почтового сервера на `postfix`. Но обновление статистики происходит только через команду в консоли. При попытке обновить через браузер выдает ошибку:

> Error: Couldn't open file "/usr/etc/awstats/awstats072012.tmp.3849" for write: Permission deniedSetup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).

В кофиг. файле `awstats` обновление через браузер включено. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

В `crontab должно быть что то вроде этого

> - - - - - /usr/local/awstats/tools/[awstats_updateall.pl](http://awstats_updateall.pl) now

где первые две звездочки будут указывать минуту часа для запуска сценария, если надо чаще чем раз в сутки смотрите `man 5 crontab`.

> суть в том, чтобы она обновлялась в любой момент по щелчку из браузера

Установил у себя, проверил, через web "обновить сейчас", нужно дать права на чтение лога. У меня это пользователь wwwrun, смотрите у себя.

Comment: Во-первых, если можно, про`crontab по-подробнее, где это и что это?Во-вторых, суть не в том, чтобы статистика обновлялась автоматически, суть в том, чтобы она обновлялась в любой момент по щелчку из браузера. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: 1. cron это "планировщик заданий" для unix2. В документации написано через crontab3. */5 * * * * /usr/local/awstats/tools/awstats_updateall.pl now - раз в 5 мин.

Comment: Установил у себя, проверил, через web "обновить сейчас", нужно дать права на чтение лога. У меня это пользователь wwwrun, смотрите у себя.